# How can I debug a stack overflow in Ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby, debugging, stack-overflow

I have some Ruby code sits on top of Chipmunk and OpenGL C libraries. Something in my program is causing a stack overflow at the C or Ruby level. I'm looking for some strategies to figure out where the majority of objects are getting created. What are your best strategies for debugging a stack overflow in Ruby 1.9+?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, stack overflows aren't caused by an excess of objects, but by excessive recursion.